# Prevent User interactions only on UIView and not on Subviews - Swift - Programmatically

Tags: swift, uiview, touch-event, uipangesturerecognizer, isuserinteractionenabled

I have a UIView subclass that I created in this way:

```
class UpperView : UIView{

var currentColor : UIColor = .white

private var lineArray: [[CGPoint]] = [[CGPoint]]()

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    
    guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
    let firstPoint = touch.location(in: self)
    
    lineArray.append([CGPoint]())
    lineArray[lineArray.count - 1].append(firstPoint)
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
    let currentPoint = touch.location(in: self)
    lineArray[lineArray.count - 1].append(currentPoint)
    setNeedsDisplay()
}

}
```

I want to prevent this UIView to receive events, so I searched online and I found out that I could set *isUserInteractionEnabled = false*

Using this method the view doesn't receive any event and so do all of its subviews.

This is the problem, how can I prevent the view to receive any touch event while still allowing its subviews to receive them?

Comment: As a side note, if you don't call super on these overrides, you have to override all of the other touch-event methods even if they're empty. In your case, better to just call super on them.

Comment: @bsod thanks for the feedback, I implemented it right now